# How To export all stores in mobx using single index.jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have the following file structure for stores:

```
user.jsx
notification.jsx
subscriber.jsx
```

Each exporting a default store. I want to create a single file index.jsx so that I can call them as required using a single file.

In redux the functionality can be achieved using combineReducers function.

Does mobx has similar option? If no then how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. create an `index.jsx` file in your store directory:

```
// stores/index.jsx
import user from './user.jsx';
import notification from './notification.jsx';
import subscriber from './subscriber.jsx';

const stores = {
  user,
  notification,
  subscriber
};

export default stores;
```

Then you can use this to e.g. inject all the stores into a Provider:

```
// app.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import stores from './stores';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider {...stores}>
    {/* ... */}
  </Provider>
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```